# Error When Publishing A Product To Online Store in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api

After creating a product I'm trying to publish it to the online store. The product is getting published but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Your app doesn't have a publication for this shop.
```

**Here is my code:**

```
// Publish the newly created product.
const publishProductRequest = await admin.graphql(
  `#graphql
  mutation publishProduct($id: ID!, $input: [PublicationInput!]!) {
    publishablePublish(id: $id, input: $input) {
      userErrors {
        field
        message
      }
      publishable {
        availablePublicationCount
        publicationCount
        publishedOnCurrentPublication
      }
      shop {
        id
        name
        publicationCount
      }
    }
  }`,
  {
    variables: {
      id: productId,
      input: {
        publicationId: onlineStorePublicationId,
      },
    },
  }
);

const publishProductResponse = await publishProductRequest.json();

return json(publishProductResponse);
```

However I found a [similar question](https://community.shopify.com/c/graphql-basics-and/update-set-publications-sales-channels-on-product-create/m-p/560928/highlight/true#M5190) in the Shopify discussion with an accepted solution which is: **The app needed storefront API access to set the product to Online Store.** But I couldn't comprehend the solution.

Can anyone please help with the issue?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Do not query `publishedOnCurrentPublication` node for `publishable` object and it will work.

```
      publishable {
        availablePublicationCount
        publicationCount
      }
```